# multiple lists with different contextMenus

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a viewFlipper with different ListViews in each "flip". I have made all the lists `registerForContextMenu(chosenList);` and the longPress menu appears in each of the lists as I want.

Now I want to have DIFFERENT contextMenues in the different list views. eg. one list with network info will have network related choices in the contextMenu and the list with friends will have another set of choices in it's contextMenu.

How do I do this efficiently? is this even possible?

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu2, menu3, menu4, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu2, menu3, menu4, v, menuInfo);
  menu2.setHeaderTitle("Quick Menu");
  menu3.setHeaderTitle("Menu3");
  menu4.setHeaderTitle("Menu4");
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu2);
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu3, menu3);
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu4, menu4);
}
```

...or ...? how else? this is starting to drive me insane in the midbrain... :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your onCreateContextMenu(), do something like:

```
switch(v.getId())
{
    case R.id.list1:
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu1, menu)
        break;
    }
    case R.id.list2:
    {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu2, menu)
        break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had some trouble and figured out I needed to be using the ID of the top level layout in your list item xml